# Retrieve values out of PFObject

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a save button to save Score and Playername to GameScore in Parse. When I load the GameScore from Parse I want to set the value that i loaded to the variable "score". This don't work, can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong? 
Thanks

Exapmle:  let score = gameScore["score"] as Int

```
// Load button tapped
@IBAction func loadButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    var query = PFQuery(className:"GameScore")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("F1efANYzOE") {
        (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil && gameScore != nil {
            println(gameScore)
            let score = gameScore["score"] as Int

        } else {
            println(error)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you tell what error you are getting??

Comment: I'm not exactly getting an error. But it wont set the score variable to what i have loaded, witch is what i want it to do.

Comment: what's the output of your statement             println(gameScore), Is it printing anything??

Comment: Optional(<GameScore: 0x7fb0aa564b50, objectId: F1efANYzOE, localId: (null)> {
    playerName = Name;
    score = 1353;
})

I want it to set the "score" variable to 1353 that i loaded.

Comment: what u get if you print out score variable after let score = gameScore['score']?

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code for retrieving specific data from specific columns. You have to enter your object name, Object ID and column name in the below code and run it. It will work.

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"Your Object name")

        query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId("Your Object ID") {
            (gameScore: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil  {
                print(gameScore!.objectForKey("your column name") as! String)
            } else {
                print(error)
            }
        }
```